# JavaScript .substr() and .slice()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this Javascript so that when my webpage opens, it will ask for a password and your name, an if you do not enter your name, it engages a loop until you do, and capitalizes the first letter in the name entered. But it will not capitalize the first letter. Please help. Thank you.

```
function startFunction() {
    var Password = prompt("What is the password?");
    getPassword(Password);
};

function getPassword(Password) {
  if (Password == "123") {
    alert("Correct password. Access granted.");
    var Name = prompt("What is your name?");
    getName(Name);
  }
  else {
    alert("Incorrect password. Access denied.");
    window.close();
  }
};

function getName(Name) {
  if (Name.length === 0) {
    while (Name.length === 0) {
    alert("Please enter your name.");
    var Name = prompt("What is your name?");
    if (Name.length > 0) {
      alert("Nice to meet you, " + Name + ".");
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    try {
      var newName2 = Name.slice(1, Number(name.length));
      var newName1 = Name.slice(0, 1);
      var newName = newName1.toUpperCase() + newName2;
      alert("Nice to meet you, " + newName + ".");
    }
    catch (ValueError) {
      alert("Hello")
    }
  }
};

startFunction();
```

Comment: Your code appears to capitalise the first letter of my name when I enter it. Are you sure your code doesn't work as expected? Also, please remember to follow [**standard JavaScript naming conventions**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp).

Comment: The "Nice to meet you..." alert that occurs in the `if` block doesn't have any code to capitalise the first letter, only the alert in the `else` block does. By the way, you shouldn't need a try/catch for this code.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I was trying to get it to capitalize the first letter and add it to the rest of the name. Like if you add ''chris", it will alert "Chris".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop didn't include the logic to capitalize the first letter of the name, so if your first attempt at entering the name was empty, its greeting wouldn't be capitalized.

I simplified `getName()` a bit and moved the capitalization to its own function:

```
function getName(Name) {
  while (Name.length === 0) {
    alert("Please enter your name.");
    Name = prompt("What is your name?");
  }

  try {
    alert("Nice to meet you, " + capitalizeName(Name) + ".");
  }
  catch (ValueError) {
    alert("Hello")
  }
};

function capitalizeName(Name) {
  var newName2 = Name.slice(1, Number(name.length));
  var newName1 = Name.slice(0, 1);
  var newName = newName1.toUpperCase() + newName2;
  return newName;
}
```

And a fiddle of it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/21mdLfrb/

Answer (score 0):

Here u go

Html :

```
<input type="text" id="name" ></input>
<input type="password" id="pass" ></input>
<button onclick="process()" >
  Submit
</button>
```

Javascript :

```
function process(){
   var getName= document.getElementById("name").value;
   var getPass= document.getElementById("pass").value;

   if(getName && getPass){
       getName = getName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + getName.slice(1);
       alert("Nice to meet you, " + getName + ".");

     }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/hcb81vng/